# Removing span tags with regex in php

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I need a regex that removes span tags for example if we have :

```
<span class="something"><strong>Hello</strong></span>
```

The output should be :

```
<strong>Hello</strong>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Utilize **DOM** to do this, https://eval.in/312496

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/<span[^>]+?[^>]+>|</span>/i','',$string)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it by doing this

```
 $tag = 'span';
     $result = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>#is', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

In `php` if you want to remove something from string then use inbuilt functions wherever possible like

- `strip_tags()` for removing all html tags from strings,
- `htmlentities()` Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities, like **Hello** to `<b>Hello</b>`, it prints html text literally(i have used in below example).

But if you want something different from basic operations like here (removing `span` tag only from html text) then you have to use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).
And below is my solution using `preg_replace()`

```
$string_without_span_tag = preg_replace('/<span[^>]+\>|<\/span>/i', '', $string_with_span_tag); 
echo htmlentities($string_without_span_tag);

//$string_with_span_tag = '<span class="something"><strong><span style="color:red;">Hello</span></strong></span>';
//output after using above regex: <strong>Hello</strong>
```

Answer of @Zdimitriv also works, so you can also use it, but if you use [@mcklayin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592397/removing-span-tags-with-regex-in-php/29592909#29592909)'s answer then be careful, i have not tested in laravel but in core php that answer will give you error as:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'p' in your_file_name.php on line XXX
```

the reason behind it is pattern used in that answer which is `/<span[^>]+?[^>]+>|</span>/i` but regex understands it as `/<span[^>]+?[^>]+>|</s` because in regex `/` is starting and ending delimeter, and it shows error `p is unknown modifier` because `s` is `single line modifier` in regex so it stops at p and gives error as above, to solve it you have to escape `/` with `\` then it will work as well.

So you can use 3 pattern as below for removing `<span>` tag:

```
 preg_replace('/<span[^>]+\>|<\/span>/i', '', $string_with_span_tag) //1. my answer
 preg_replace('#</?span[^>]*>#is', '', $string_with_span_tag) //2.@Zdimitriv's answer
 preg_replace('/<span[^>]+?[^>]+>|<\/span>/i', '', $string_with_span_tag) //3.@mcklayin's answer with edit
```