# Regex to remove span tags using php

Tags: php, regex, stock

Following is simple html i want to remove all span tag and just want 0.65 value. please someone help me on this.

```
<span class="smw smw-inline smw-basic smw-ct-default smw-visible" data-symbol="GSD.V" data-type="inline" data-refresh-frequency="5" data-source="live">
<span class="smw-market-data-field smw-field-l1" data-field="l1">0.65</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Use `DOM` parser.

Comment: can you please write code for me

Comment: you could use strip_tags() for that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @SandeepKumar check my answer it will help you for both html and span tag remove

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove all tag using `preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $content);`

And also you can remove only span tag `preg_replace('/<span[^>]+\>/i', '', $content);` using this:

```
<?php 
$content = '<div><span class="smw smw-inline smw-basic smw-ct-default smw-visible" data-symbol="GSD.V" data-type="inline" data-refresh-frequency="5" data-source="live">
<span class="smw-market-data-field smw-field-l1" data-field="l1">0.65</span>
</span></div>';

echo $string =  preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $content);

echo $new_string = preg_replace('/<span[^>]+\>/i', '', $content); 
?>
```

Comment: i have used your answer but it is not removing `</span>` span close tag, i have seen it still exist in string when using `htmlentities($string)`, to remove the close tag also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592397/removing-span-tags-with-regex-in-php/52608422#52608422).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and regex:

```
<?php

$html = '<span class="smw smw-inline smw-basic smw-ct-default smw-visible" data-symbol="GSD.V" data-type="inline" data-refresh-frequency="5" data-source="live">
<span class="smw-market-data-field smw-field-l1" data-field="l1">0.65</span>
</span>';

$without_span = $html;
$without_span = preg_replace('#\n\r#', '', $without_span);
$without_span = preg_replace('#\n#', '', $without_span);

while(preg_match_all('#(<span.*?>)(.*?)(</span>)#', $without_span)) {  
  $without_span = preg_replace('#(<span.*?>)(.*?)(</span>)#', '$2', $without_span);
}

print_r($without_span);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming PHP and Perl are similar enough for this ...

`s{\</?span[^>]*/?>}{}gism`

hth

Answer (score -2):

please try this below code.

```
 $string = '<span class="smw smw-inline smw-basic smw-ct-default smw-visible" data-symbol="GSD.V" data-type="inline" data-refresh-frequency="5" data-source="live">
<span class="smw-market-data-field smw-field-l1" data-field="l1">0.65</span>
</span>';

 echo strip_tags($string);
```