# PHP Regex Pattern, removing span tags and inner text from string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to format an array of strings, in order to strip out statements like this:

```
*<span class="exception">some text</span>
```

Many of these array items are just decimal numbers, but several instances contain html tags/text such as above.  Here's some sample items from the array, to help put it into perspective:

```
'1.5',
'3.7',
'8.0',
'4.2*<span class="exception">some text</span>'
'5.7*<span class="exception">some text</span>random text to keep'
'4.9*<span class="exception">some text</span>8.0'
```

When I encounter items with '*some text', I need to remove the asterisk, the opening and closing span tags, and the text within the tags completely.  The text within the tags is completely random.  Additional text may follow the span tags, and in this case I would need to keep that text.

I've checked out several posts, including the following (the most helpful so far), but with only partial success: [Regex to remove span tags using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559607/regex-to-remove-span-tags-using-php)

```
if (substr_count($value, '*<span') > 0) {
  $value = preg_replace('/<span[^>]+\>/', '', $value);
}
```

This statement strips off the asterisk and the opening span tag, but not the closing span tag or the text between tags.

I'm fairly new to regex so any help or advice is certainly appreciated.

Comment: Is it always everything after the * that you want to get rid of?

Comment: It is, there is always an asterisk preceding the span tag.

Comment: so.. you want to replace `'4.2*<span class="exception">some text</span>'`  with `'4.2""""'` then? (4x because the asterisk is #1, the opening tag is #2, the inner text is #3, and the closing tag is #4)

Comment: @hanshenrik, I've updated the post to reflect some additional info.  I want to remove the asterisk, span tags and all text between the span tags completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be it.. The [*] matches the * character while the .*> matches any up till the > character

```
 if (substr_count($value, '*<span') > 0) {
      $value = preg_replace('/[*].*>/', '', $value);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this works great!  I modified it slightly in case there's any additional html tags after the closing span tag.  `$value = preg_replace('/[*].*\/span>/', '', $value);`

Answer (score 2):

If everything follows this pattern, you don't need a regex just explode on the * and use the first element.

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
  $array[$key] = explode('*',$value)[0];
}
```

Result from your example:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "1.5"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "3.7"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "8.0"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "4.2"
}
```

**EDIT**
If there is "other stuff" after the tags it takes a little more work

```
$array = [
  '1.5',
  '3.7',
  '8.0*<span class="exception">some text</span>',
  '4.2*<span class="exception">some text</span>then other stuff'
];

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
  $sub = explode('*',$value);
  $end = [];
  if(count($sub) > 1) {
    $end = explode('>',end($sub));
  }
  $array[$key] = trim($sub[0] . ' ' . end($end));
}
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "1.5"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "3.7"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "8.0"
  [3]=>
  string(20) "4.2 then other stuff"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work.  In many cases, the string has additional values (a random mix of numbers and letters) after the span tags that I need to keep.

Comment: @Xthralls then add a sample where this approach won't work to your main post

Comment: @ArleighHix, this does work, but I was looking for a regex specific pattern such as the one Fithage provided.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply capture all components of unexpected HTMLs, then replace with anything that you wish, with a simple expression such as:

```
([0-9.]+)(.+?)<(.+?)>(.+?)<(\/.+?)>
```

Here, `([0-9.]+)` captures the number in `$1`, followed by * in `$2`, `(.+?)`, then open tag in `$3`, `<(.+?)>`, textConent in `$4` `(.+?)` and closing tag in `$5`, `<(\/.+?)>`, and we can modify that, if we wish to capture anything else.

#### Test

```
$re = '/([0-9.]+)(.+?)<(.+?)>(.+?)<(\/.+?)>/m';
$str = '4.2*<span class="exception">some text</span>';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRac56/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[Do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003). use a proper HTML parser instead, in your case

```
$arr = array(
    '1.5',
    '3.7',
    '8.0',
    '4.2*<span class="exception">some text</span>',
    '5.7*<span class="exception">some text</span>random text to keep',
    '4.9*<span class="exception">some text</span>8.0',
);

foreach ($arr as &$tmp) {
    $domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8"><main>' . $tmp . '</main>');
    $main = $domd->getElementsByTagName("main")->item(0);
    foreach ($main->getElementsByTagName("*") as $remove) {
        $remove->parentNode->removeChild($remove);
    }
    $tmp = str_replace("*", " ", $main->textContent);
}

print_r($arr);
```

yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.5
    [1] => 3.7
    [2] => 8.0
    [3] => 4.2 
    [4] => 5.7 random text to keep
    [5] => 4.9 8.0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = ['1.5',
'3.7',
'8.0',
'4.2*<span class="exception">some text</span>',
'5.7*<span class="exception">some text</span>random text to keep' ,
'4.9*<span class="exception">some text</span>8.0'];
foreach($value as $k=>$v){
    $value[$k] = strip_tags($v);
}
print_r($value);
```